# Managing a Large Number of Test Variables in Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

My program works with a large number of objects, and the actions the program performs on the objects, depend on the type of the object and its configuration. This configuration can be customized via configurations files.

When writing tests for this program, I have to write tests for the module that parses the configuration files. To do that, I create a variable for every parameter name/value pair of the configuration. I then write those variables (and their values) to the configuration files in the setup of the tests.
I do this because I need to know exactly what is contained in the configuration files when I want to verify the output of the parser. Another reason I do it this way, is because the parsing should work with several types of formats (e.g., delimiters, values indicating empty elements, etc.).

An example/template config file, is a YAML file that looks like this:

```
all:
  all_setting1: "all_setting1_value"
  all_setting2: "all_setting2_value"

customer:
  all:
    all_customers_setting1: "all_customers_setting1_value"
    all_customers_setting2: "all_customers_setting2_value"
  customer1:
    customer1_setting1: "customer1_setting1_value"
    customer1_setting2: "customer1_setting2_value"

  customer2:
    customer2_setting1: "customer2_setting1_value"
    customer2_setting2: "customer2_setting2_value"  

type:
  all:
    all_types_setting1: "all_types_setting1_value"
    all_types_setting2: "all_types_setting2_value"
  type1:
    type1_setting1: "type1_setting1_value"
    type1_setting2: "type1_setting2_value"
  type2:
    type2_setting1: "type2_setting1_value"
    type2_setting2: "type2_setting2_value"

scope:
  all:
    all_scopes_setting1: "all_scopes_setting1_value"
    all_scopes_setting2: "all_scopes_setting2_value"
  scope1:
    scope1_setting1: "scope1_setting1_value"
    scope1_setting2: "scope1_setting2_value"
  scope2:
    scope2_setting1: "scope2_setting1_value"
    scope2_setting2: "scope2_setting2_value"
```

Pytest setup code to create such a test configuration file, looks like this:

```
pytest.attribute_all_setting1_name = "all_setting1"
pytest.attribute_all_setting1_value = "all_setting1_value"
pytest.attribute_all_setting2_name = "all_setting2"
pytest.attribute_all_setting2_value = "all_setting2_value"

pytest.attribute1_name = "customer"
pytest.attribute1_all_name = "all"
pytest.attribute1_all_setting1_name = "all_customers_setting1"
pytest.attribute1_all_setting1_value = "all_customers_setting1_value"
...
etc.
...
pytest.attribute3_name = "scope"
pytest.attribute3_all_name = "all"
...
```

As you can see, I'm saving each element of the configuration as a global pytest variable, which I can then access in every test.

Is there any better way to achieve this?
I'm running into failed tests when I run all tests in random order, and I assume this is caused by all tests using the same global variables.

Answer (score 0):

this might be a job for [parameterized](https://pypi.org/project/parameterized/)

it allows you to write a single test with multiple inputs and then have it look like this:

```
@parameterized([
    (2, 2, 4),
    (2, 3, 8),
    (1, 9, 1),
    (0, 9, 0),
])
def test_pow(base, exponent, expected):
   assert_equal(math.pow(base, exponent), expected)
```

As you can see, all the test cases are passed as a `tuple`. This is cool because you can even parameterise that set of test cases, maybe load it from a JSON or YAML file.

In this way you can store all of your different test configurations away from the test file and load them for each test run in a precise manner.

Comment: I already use parameterized tests and Pytest's generate-tests functionality. However, I fail to see how it might help me with testing a config parser.

Comment: you can pass the config YAML as a parameter to the test case, that way it's loaded when the test runs and only for that test

Comment: I'm testing the functionality of the parser that parses the config YAML. I guess I could, as you suggested, create a test YAML file and parse that during the test. However, that means that the content of that test YAML file is not in any variables, and I, therefore, have to hard-code the test assertions. Meaning that I have to change the tests whenever I change the YAML.